# The field of polarized object derivation in Griffith's Intro to Electrodynamics (4th ed, section 4.2.1)

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, polarization

In the derivation, Griffith says "a little sleight-of-hand casts this integral into a much more illuminating form", then presents the following without proof.

$\nabla' \left( \frac{1}{R}\right) = \left(\frac{\mathbf{\hat{R}}}{R^2}\right)$

where $R  = \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} $ and $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector pointing from the origin to the point of interest, and $\mathbf{r'}$ is a vector pointing from the source charge to the point of interest.

Notice that the differentiation is with respect to the source coordinates $\mathbf{r'}$

My attempt was to do the following

$\nabla' \left( \frac{1}{R}\right) = \nabla' \left( \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{r'}} \left( \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|} \right)$

I am not sure how to carry out this derivative.. where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Brick Whoops, yes that's a mistake. I'll fix it right now.

Comment: Try to evaluate this gradient in cartesian coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way, but as @KP99 pointed out the application of the gradient in Cartesian form is straightforward:

$$ \nabla' \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2}}\right)$$

Noting that $$\nabla'f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}  \hat i + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}  \hat j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z'}  \hat k$$

Executing each partial derivative gives:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{(x-x')}{((x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2)^{3/2}}$$

Etc...

So $$\nabla'f = \frac{1}{r^3} \left<x-x', y-y', z-z' \right>$$

But $$ \frac{1}{r}\left<x-x', y-y', z-z' \right> = \hat r$$

Therefore:

$$\nabla'f = \frac{1}{r^2} \hat r$$